# How do you respond_to another js file in the controller using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I basically have an action that because of logic needs to return with the contents of another js file.  How do I go about doing this?  Thanks

app/controllers/classrooms_controller.rb

```
def create
  if params[:test_logic]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'create_differently' } # This doesn't work.
    end
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

app/views/classrooms/create_differently.js.erb

```
alert('hi')
```

Comment: Its showing this in the backend: `Processing by ClassroomsController#create as HTML` Why would that happen if I specifically told it to return js?

Comment: That message appeared since you have requested HTML page and is printed before controller code is executed. So what is the result of that call? What do you see in browser? Is there an exception?

Comment: It sends me to a blank page (checked the source).  Why is it sending me to a blank page with errors and in HTML?

Comment: how is the url, you are calling? remember, if you call http://localhost:3000/classrooms/1 a request for html will be made. Only http://localhost:3000/classrooms/1.js will render to javascript.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add

```
 :layout => false
```

to [avoid the rendering of the html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-layout-option) layout for your js file.

Additionally you could define the different js-file like this

```
:template => "classrooms/create_differently.js.erb"
```

both together:

```
 format.js { 
    render :template => "classrooms/create_differently.js.erb", 
           :layout => false  
 }
```

For browser-based testing, please be aware calling js not html!