# How to replace HTML with javascript in RAILS 5

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to replace a value in my front to an other value without realoding the page.

I succeed to make it so far but I'm honestly not sure to understand what I did.

What I want to do is:

When an user upvote an article, the counter increased by one if the user click on it again it decreased by one. Simple.

I have my Upvote controller

```
  def create
    if upvote
      upvote.destroy
      msg = 'Upvote removed'
    else
      Upvote.create(upvote_params)
    end
    set_article
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { head :success }
      format.js   { render js: "alert('#{msg}')" if msg }
    end
  end

protected

  def upvote
      @upvote ||= Upvote.find_by(article_id: params[:upvote][:article_id])
  end

  def upvote_params
    params.require(:upvote).permit(:user_id, :article_id, :activate)
  end

  def set_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:upvote][:article_id])
  end
```

I have my `views/article/show.html.erb`

```
          <div style="flex: 1 0 33%;">
            <%= button_to upvotes_path, method: :post, params: { upvote: { user_id: current_user, article_id: @article } }, remote: true, class: "button-link" do %>
            <div class="button_container">
              <span>+<span id="article-votes"><%= @article.upvotes_count %></span></span>
              추천
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
```

and my `views/upvotes/create.js.erb`

```
$("#article-votes").html("<%= @article.upvotes_count %>")
```

Isn't it there another way to do it ? I feel like there is lot of repetition by creating a javascript file with the name of the method for each model and method we do remote.

Also I don't understand why in my case my javascript is well executed when I first upvote but when it delete the upvote `create.js.erb` is not executed.

I'm lost on how rails and javascript are working together and I don't know how I can do better.

I have search all the day and I found only this solution.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Check the guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html. If you don't want to create a new `.js` view for an action you can use what you aready did to display the alert, use `render js: ...` with the code if it's a oneliner.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I didn't thought about using `rende js: ...` so I finally followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167596/how-do-you-respond-to-another-js-file-in-the-controller-using-ruby-on-rails for rendering the js I want